# How to export gridview(wpf) to csv ? i know the solution but i get only header as the output?

Tags: c#

I am trying to export data from GridView WPF to CSV. i know there are multiple solutions to it , i have also tried many. i will list the one i have tried.
the problem is things work fine i get the csv file as output but with only header.

**C# code :**

```
        var grid = myGrid;
        grid.SelectAllCells();

        grid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;

        System.Windows.Input.ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, grid);

        String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        //grid.UnselectAllCells();
        System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\test.csv");

        file1.WriteLine(result);
        file1.Close();
```

**Output file :**

test.csv

one, two , three (Headers)

,,,,,

,,,,

,,,,

Comment: SelectAllCells is only selecting one row of the grid.  You need to enumerate through the rows of the grid.

Comment: enumerate how? i am very new to c sharp can you provide some code? or do you mean iterate?

Comment: Enumerate means using a loop like a for loop to get each row of data.

Comment: can there be any other approach ? to export the data , i am using OLEDB to import the CSV but export will save only the grid values, whereas i want to update the existing values

Comment: With text files you have to write entire file in windows.  Updating a file will take longer because you have to search for old data before changing.  It is quicker just to save everything.  If you had a real database it would be different.

Comment: yes you are correct .